# What is the proper hook to use for recording a post view?

Tags: hooks

I'm creating a script for tracking post views in my future projects. I will use this code in my theme's `functions.php`.

What I'm asking is, how can I make sure a post view is recorded when a user actually hits the page?

I considered hooking into `init` or `wp`, but I'm not sure using the REST API and Ajax actions will also trigger a hit (which I want it to).

Is it possible?

Comment: The hook you want to use depends on where/when you want to record a 'view': on the home page, where you have full posts or excerpts? On an individual post page? On other page types? More info needed on exactly when you want to record a visit. But it seems to me that using Google Analytics will tell you more about the activities of the visitor.

Comment: So, seems like I have to write different function for different pages/conditions?

Comment: See answer below, since you provided additional info on what you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears you want to track each kind of page view (which is what Google Analytics would do for you if you don't want to roll your own), then create a function that will use the current page-type, or even any type of page.

A function like (rough code)

```
function record_view($pagetype = 'post') { // function with default value

switch ($pagetype ) {
case "post":
  //do something
  break;
case "page":
  // do something for a pge
  break;
// add additional cases for whatever you are trackin
case default:
  // do something if not any of the above types
  break;
}
return;
}
```

See this page in the Codex for info about page types: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types .

Then put a call for the function in the template of the various page types

```
record_view('post');  // this on the single post template
```

That might get you started, if I understand your question and comments correctly.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was trying to avoid changing template files. Also google analytic's data won't help, since I'm tracking views for post sorting, rating, etc :)

Comment: There are tons of different hooks to use when a page/post displays. Once you figure out the right one (depends on when you want the function to fire), just put that add_action() in your Child Theme's function.php file (Child theme to avoid affecting the primary theme, so that your changes aren't overwritten on a theme update.) If you use the correct hook, you can get the page type variable from the WP query, and use that in the function. (If an answer is what you need, click the checkmark to indicate that the answer could be helpful to others.)

Comment: This code will not run when a REST API request is made.